# Script for IBM Rhapsody made with Java and Spring autowiring not working

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, autowired, rhapsody

I developed a script for IBM Rhapsody using it's API for java.
The script is working fine when is run from my IDE. When I run the script from Rhapsody using the JAR and HEP file I get NullPointerException when I use autowired beans.

Does anyone know if the Spring is nor supported for Rhapsody API or haw I can fix my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to export as an executable JAR. This way the JAR is exported with the necessary library included.
My problem was that when Rhapsody run my JAR file it did not find spring in the classpath.